# Possible ajax call to result in extreme load times after redirects?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have the following senario

Page A is being loaded and fires up 3 ajax calls, they take some time because they are working on getting a lot of data, though nothing the server can't handle. Now the user is redirecting to page B before the ajax calls have finished. I know they will continue running on the background, but could this possible cause dramatic loading times? There is no sql overheat, server processor is only using around 10% of it's limits. Yet loading times can differ from 1-2 seconds all the way to 50+ seconds.

Is it possible that this is being caused by the previous, yet running ajax calls and that the browser is somehow still having a connection with these calls and awaits response before it will load the next page??

Comment: are you using sessions ?

Comment: Depends, if we use the session library? Yes we do, if the ajax calls are using it? No. Not sure how relevant the session would be for page loading?

Comment: You can abort all active ajax on unload event, if you wish

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer in the comment section i try to explain it and provide a solution for this - because i ran a ton of times in this issue - although you write that your ajax calls are not using the session library - check out if you start it anyway.

PHP writes session data to a file by default. If a request starts it starts the session. This session file is locked. What this means is that if your web page makes a ton of requests to PHP scripts, e.g. for loading content via Ajax, each request locks the session and prevents the other requests to complete.

What we did in order to prevent situations like that is the following:

in your /application/config/hooks.php

```
$hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
    "class" => "AppSessionInterceptor",
    "function" => "initialize",
    "filename" => "AppSessionInterceptor.php",
    "filepath" => "hooks"
);
```

and after that create a hook called AppSessionInterceptor

```
class AppSessionInterceptor
{

    private $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci = &get_instance();
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        //some doings
        $this->closeSession();
    }

    private function closeSession()
    {
        $blnSessWriteClose = true;

        $arrStopSessionFromWriteClose = array(
            $this->ci->uri->segment(1) => array("logout","login"),
            $this->ci->uri->segment(2) => array("logout","login"),
            $this->ci->input->get("blnWriteSession") => array(1)
        );

        foreach($arrStopSessionFromWriteClose AS $key => $arrValue)
        {
            if (in_array($key, $arrValue))
            {
                $blnSessWriteClose = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($blnSessWriteClose) session_write_close();
    }
}
```

This closes the session before anything else is called.
Keep in mind that if you close a session - you are able to read the data but can't write it anymore.